# How to start a project without eclipse ?And please rate my project

Tags: java

For the last few days I have been working on a little project of mine.A game.It's first playable and in my opinion stable version is ready.
I was wondering if you could test it out and give me some opinions.

Also I would love to get some feedback .
And please tell me how to start the game without eclipse?

here's a link:
https://github.com/k0k0gada/some-game-

Comment: Your question about "rate my project" are off-topic for this site. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Your first question is potentially appropriate, but there are many tutorials on how to run a Java program without an IDE -- what have you tried and how isn't it working?

Comment: could you suggest me a site where I could get some feedback for the project of mine.
as for the tutorials.I'd look for some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply as follows in **Eclipse** :

```
Right click on your Java Project and select Export.

Select Java -> Runnable JAR file -> Next.

Select the Launch Configuration and choose project file as your Main class

Select the Destination folder where you would like to save it and click Finish
```

If you want executable file like .exe then you can you tools like [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/download.html)

Comment: In order later on to start the jar fail.You need to find it in the console and then use:   java -jar ".jar".
Thank you for the answer. :D 
do you have a suggestion about where I can find some1 to review my game ?

Comment: I don't have any suggestion for that because I am also unknown of that. I think you need to provide review or rating feature in your game and promote your game and make some users and If they like your game or have some errors they may review your game. :)